# Connect from php to oracle database in windows x64

Tags: php, database, oracle, oracle-xe

I am trying to connect from php to oracle database in windows x64

I use: php5, apache2, oraclexe 10.2

My file "test.php" is the following:

```
 <?php
  if ($c = oci_connect("SYSTEM", "root", "//localhost:1521/XE")) {
   echo "Successfully connected to Oracle.";
   oci_close($c);
  } else {
   $err = oci_error();
   echo "Oracle Connect Error " . $err['text'];
  }
 ?>
```

When I open localhost/test.php, getting a following error:

```
Warning: oci_connect() [function.oci-connect]: ORA-06413: Connection not open
```

I can not understand the cause of this error, because I have already connected to the same database from Java, and I think the php.ini file is well configured, because I managed to connect from php to MySQL database.
Also followed this tutorial: http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/PHP_FAQ

So if someone have a solutions and comments post it please

Comment: On a sidenote: There's a big manual from Oracle about using PHP and Oracle DB on http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/php/underground-php-oracle-manual-098250.html

Comment: I tried to follow all the steps that are in this pdf. 've also tried to use ' instead of " but not results. Thanks for the suggestion. This book seems very complete. I'll try to reinstall php and follow the manual again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is XE the service name of your database?  That's the name used in the example code that you have to change.

Comment: Yes. In Oracle SQL Developer proprities looks like this: connection_name:projecto_bd, username:SYSTEM, hostname:localhost, port:1521, SID:xe

Comment: Verify with "lsnrctl status". That will also make sure the listener is up and the DB is registered.  The error itself is generic.  You'll need some debug output from PHP to see where it actually failed.

Comment: I had added this code in the beginning of php script : ini_set ("display_errors", "1");
error_reporting(E_ALL); but got no error message. Also used lsnrctr and ran command: status and got three listening endpoint status with Andriy-PC host = port = 1521 host = 127.0.0.1 and port = 8080 there is some mistake here?